# django, limit generics.ListAPIView by week of user entered filterset_field

Tags: python, django-views, django-pagination

New to django and kicking off with an api. I would like for my view to accept a filter set field and then return data within one week greater than that field. The view I have set up currently is

views.py

```
class MeterView(generics.ListAPIView):

    queryset = MeterLake.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MeterLakeSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = {'siteid' : ['exact'], 
                        'createdtimestamp' : ['gte'],
                        
                        }
```

the user would then enter url/?createdtimestamp=date
I would then like to take the user entered date and return information greater than one week of that date.

Ideally, I would like to use pagination for this but I am not sure how
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can customise how createdtimestamp filter field gets used by providing a custom filterset_class to be used instead of the shorthand way that you use currently.

For example, by providing the method for the filter you can adjust the value used for the lookup.

```py
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class MeterLakeFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    createdtimestamp = filters.BooleanFilter(
        field_name='createdtimestamp', method='filter_a_week_from_date'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MeterLake
        fields = ['createdtimestamp', 'siteid']

    def filter_a_week_from_date(self, queryset, name, value):
        lookup = f'{name}__gte'
        dateformat = '%Y-%m-%d' # replace with expected value format.
        # value may be serialized already, thus not needing to be parsed here.
        value = datetime.strptime(value, dateformat) + timedelta(days=7)
        return queryset.filter(**{lookup: value})


class MeterView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = MeterLake.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MeterLakeSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = MeterLakeFilter
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great on filtering by the siteid but it is struggling on the filter by date. I think the issue is probably something to do with my datetime value. What's the best way to check what the value is? Normally I would print it out but I am having trouble accessing the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Using Oluwafemi Sule's answer I was able to tweak the custom filter and generic view to search by siteid and one week from the entered time stamp. I also added in some functionality to limit the time range to one week from today if no timestamp is specified.

```
class MeterLakeFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    siteid = filters.CharFilter(field_name='siteid')
    createdtimestamp = DateTimeFilter(field_name = 'createdtimestamp', method = 'filter_a_week_from_date')
    
    class Meta:
        model = MeterLake
        fields = ['siteid', 'createdtimestamp']

    def filter_a_week_from_date(self,queryset, name, value):
        
        if self.request.query_params.get('createdtimestamp', 'None') == None:
            lookup = f'{name}__gte'
            value = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=7)
            return queryset.filter(**{lookup: value})
        
        else:
            value2 = value + timedelta(days=7)
            return queryset.filter(createdtimestamp__lte = value2, createdtimestamp__gte = value)

class MeterView(generics.ListAPIView):
    
    queryset = MeterLake.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MeterLakeSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend,OrderingFilter]
    filterset_class = MeterLakeFilter
    ordering_fields = ['siteid', 'createdtimestamp']
    ordering = ['siteid', 'createdtimestamp']

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.query_params.get('createdtimestamp', None) == None:
            start_date = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
            end_date = start_date - timedelta(days=7)
            queryset = MeterLake.objects.filter(createdtimestamp__gte = end_date).order_by('createdtimestamp')
            
            return queryset
        else:
            
            pass
```